# Overwrite previous values with last one given some group

Tags: r, dplyr, populate

I have transposed and populated a data frame which now looks like this:

[image]

Now I am trying to overwrite all of the values in columns Signal1 and Signal 2 in upward direction by grouping them by ID and Date simultaneously. All of the previous rows should be populated by the last value for a given group. The output should look like this:

[image]

I tried to approach the problem with dplyr but not sure how to handle it:

df %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% mutate (...)

Have to perform this operation on many more columns (Signal1 - Signal 30) so hopefully an universal solution is available.

Comment: Please provide your example data with using `dput` on your data and copying the resulting text/code into your question, don't use images to show the data

Comment: maybe this works? `df_new <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Signal"), last()))`

Comment: @starja  what is the significant of the `last()` can u explain pls?

Comment: @linkonabe I've made a mistake there, it should only be `last`. `last` returns the last value for every column (taking the grouping variable into account), because @Pavel Kaloferov wants to replace all values in a group/Signal column with the last value

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  mutate(
    Signal1 = last(Signal1),
    Signal2 = last(Signal2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

EDIT: Didn't see the last part of the question. @starja 's comment is right on the money; to apply to many columns use -

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Signal"), last)) %>%
  ungroup()
```